# Cobertura data file not getting updated

Tags: java, ant, cobertura

I am trying to find out functional code coverage for my JAVA classes.
My java classes are deployed on a server as a JAR file. (**Note: It is not deployed in any application server such as tomcat**). After deploying my JAR file to server I instrumented that jar file using ant task. Classes inside my jar file are now instrumented (I confimred that by decompiling the classes). When I run my application (which in turn will access my classes from JAR file) it should created a new data file (.ser file) and add code coverage information into it. But No new data file is getting created neither is old data-file getting updated.

My project structure on server is as follows

```
Main-Folder
|--cobertura-2.1.1
|--ccbuild.xml
|--cobertura.ser (created during instrumentation)
|--lib
    |---code.jar (This file contains my instrumented classes)
    |---other-dependency.jar (All other dependencies)
    |---cobertura.jar
```

Why are my class files not generating code coverage information?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while generating .ser file. My problem resolved after changing the version of one dependent lib commons-io to V2.4